# InvalidResponseError: Returned error: unknown account

Tags: web3js, signtransaction, unknown-account, account-recovery

I'm attempting to sign a transaction using an account stored locally on my system. In the code below, you can see that I'm reading the file of that account and all other accounts stored using the `accountAdd()` function. Subsequently, I'm trying to create and sign a transaction with the `sign()` function using the first account retrieved. However, when executing this code, the following error is thrown:

```
innerError: { code: -32000, message: 'unknown account' },
  code: 101,
  data: undefined,
  request: {
    jsonrpc: '2.0',
    id: '47a1de16-4d0c-4d49-b209-5b1051965721',
    method: 'eth_signTransaction',
    params: [
      {
        from: '0xB865cA35C149DFaad9f5A76A0fc285Bc7D8501D7',
        to: '0xf904D0FDF22D13BEfAb481c937ee5b2745268351',
        value: '0x5af3107a4000',
        nonce: '0x1',
        gasPrice: '0x49877025',
        gas: '0x5208'
      }
    ]
  }
```

The whole code I tried that:

```
const {Web3}=require("web3");
const fs=require("fs");
const web3=new Web3("https://rpc.sepolia.org");
const accounts=[];

accountAdd().then(async function(){
    await sign(accounts[0].address,accounts[1].address,0.0001);
})

async function accountAdd(){
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        const data=fs.readFileSync("E:/NodeJS/accounts/account"+i+".json");
        const accountJSON=JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data));
        accounts[i]=await web3.eth.accounts.decrypt(accountJSON,"<password>");
    }
}

async function sign(fromAddress,toAddress,ethValue){
    const transaction={
        from:fromAddress,
        to:toAddress,
        value:web3.utils.toWei(ethValue,"ether")
    }
    transaction.nonce=(await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(transaction.from));
    transaction.nonce++;
    transaction.gasPrice=await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
    transaction.gasLimit=await web3.eth.estimateGas(transaction);
    const signedTx=await web3.eth.signTransaction(transaction,transaction.from);
    return signedTx;
}
```

How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it:

```
const signedTx=await accounts[0].signTransaction(transaction);
```

Instead:

```
const signedTx=await web3.eth.signTransaction(transaction,transaction.from);
```

In `sign()` function and that solved the issue!